# OpenMP executes only one thread at a time

Tags: c++, multithreading, stl, openmp

Here's my code:

```
template <unsigned int DIM>
MyVector<DIM> MyVector<DIM>::operator+(MyVector& other) {
    MyVector ans = MyVector<DIM>();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DIM; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
        ans.values_[i] = values_[i] + other.values_[i];
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Where values_ is an std::vector templated on double and DIM is something like 1024.

I compiled it using 'g++ -std=c++14 -fopenmp -g'

There is little to no difference with the performance I get when I don't use OpenMP even though I do have several threads.

Indeed, the line:

```
std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
```

shows that threads are executed one at a time...

The output is clean and is something like 11111..., 22222..., 00000..., 33333... and htop shows only one core at 100% all the time, the same one during the whole execution.

I've tried on several machines with several distributions it is everywhere the same.

Comment: a) You need to compile with `-O2` or `-O3` to get any meaningful performance behavior. b) The `cout` in the loop will dominate the observed performance and cannot be sped up in parallel. c) 1024 is a fairly small value, I would not be surprised if OMP does not yield much of an performance boost, if any.

Comment: I tried removing cout and use the optimization flags and it didn't change much about the work distribution between threads. I increased the value up to (1 << 26) and the thread were still working one at a time. So i added a this_thread::sleep_for(1us) and it worked. Is it possible that this problem come from the vector which can't write too much things at the same time for some obscure reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to rewrite your code like this to prevent the huge overhead of the I/O (which also more or less serialises the program execution):

```
template <unsigned int DIM>
MyVector<DIM> MyVector<DIM>::operator+(MyVector& other) {
    MyVector ans = MyVector<DIM>();
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        #pragma omp critical(console_io)
        {
            // The following are actually two function calls and a critical
            // region is needed in order to ensure I/O atomicity
            std::cout << omp_get_thread_num() << std::endl;
        }
        #pragma omp for schedule(static)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < DIM; ++i)
        {
            ans.values_[i] = values_[i] + other.values_[i];
        }
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Make sure `DIM` is both big enough so that the overhead of OpenMP is small compared to the work being done and in the same time small enough that the vectors fit into the CPU's last-level cache. Once the latter is no longer the case, your loop becomes memory-bound and adding new threads won't result in faster computations.

Comment: Sorry the cout part was just for debugging to see if all threads were executed at the same time. But adding this_thread::sleep_for() made all the thread work at the same time so I think you are right and it is cache problem...

Comment: You state that `DIM` is 1024. That makes 24 KiB in total for three such arrays. This is pretty small and modern CPUs usually have several MiBs of LLC. I assume you are either using your `operator+` multiple times for a small set of vectors and then it's likely that the OpenMP overhead is just too high or for a really large set of vectors and then the cache is not enough.